# HAML cycle 2 variables

Tags: haml, each, cycle

I have an each cycle like this:

```
- (1..7).each do |i|
    %li{:class => "i#{i}"}
        %a{:href => "itinerary#{i}"}#{i}
```

That produce this HTML code:

```
<li class="i1">
    <a href="#itinerary1">1</a>
</li>
<li class="i2">
    <a href="#itinerary2">2</a>
</li>
```

I need to change the cycle to create this other HTML code:

```
<li class="i1">
    <a href="#itinerary1">one</a>
</li>
<li class="i2">
    <a href="#itinerary2">two</a>
</li>
... etc
```

How can I do?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I find a solution. Something like:

```
- a = 1
- it_name = ["uno", "due", "tre"]
- it_name.each do |i|
    %li{:class => "i#{a}"}
        %a{:href => "itinerary#{a}"}#{i}
        - a+=1
```

Is there a better and cleanest way?